# How to divide all cells in a data frame by the cell on the same row of a particular column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide each cell of every column by the cell of one particular column in the same row. For example, given the dataframe:

```
A  B  C    D
6  9  4    2
4  5  11   3
8 16  12   8
```

I want to divide the values of A, B and C by the value in D of the same row. It should produce the output:

```
     A     B    C    D
     3    4.5   2    2
     1.3  1.6  3.6   3
     1     2   1.5   8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].div(df.D, axis='index')`

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without listing the columns? My dataframe is 63 columns long.

Comment: You can use `loc` to get a range of columns

Comment: Perfect, thank you!